# Как вызвать функцию doSign из скрипта js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angular, scope

Мне на ajax приходит результат,при успешном выполнении требуется вызвать функцию doSign, попробовал различные варианты,не могу понять как,не мой профиль

Обычно выскакивает при вызове ошибка uncaught type or undefined

```html
<script>
  const app = angular.module('App', []);

  app.directive('customOnChange', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
        const onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
        element.on('change', onChangeHandler);
        element.on('$destroy', () => {
          element.off();
        });
      }
    };
  });

  app.controller('Crypto', ($scope) => {
    $scope.certs = [];
    $scope.selectedCert = null;
    $scope.signInfo = null;
    $scope.data = '{{Auth::user()->name}}';
    $scope.files = null;
    $scope.sign = '';
    $scope.from = 'sender';
    $scope.pluginReady = false;

    let crypto = new CryptoHelper();

    crypto.init().then(() => {
      $scope.pluginReady = true;

      crypto.getCertificates().then((certs) => {
        $scope.certs = certs;
        $scope.$digest();
      });
    });

    $scope.doSign = (data, global_doc_id, from, download = false) => {
      crypto

        .sign($scope.selectedCert.$original, global_doc_id, doc_id, $scope.from)
        .then((signMessage) => {
          $scope.sign = signMessage;
          console.log('Идет подпись');
          if (download) {
            if (signMessage instanceof Array) {
              signMessage.forEach((sign, i) => {
                downloadData(sign, `${$scope.files[i].name}.sig`, 'text/plain');
              });
            } else {
              downloadData(signMessage, `signature.sig`, 'text/plain');
            }
          }

          $scope.$digest();
        });
    };

    $scope.doVerify = () => {
      crypto
        .verify($scope.data, $scope.sign, true)
        .then((verifyResult) => {
          if (verifyResult) {
            $scope.signInfo = verifyResult;
            $scope.$digest();
          }
        });
    };

    $scope.openFile = ($event) => {
      $scope.files = $event.target.files;
      $scope.$digest();
    };

    function downloadData(data, name, type) {
      const file = new Blob([data], {
        type
      });
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      link.download = name;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.remove();
    }

  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  var global_doc_id = "";

  function setimage() {
    var $input = $("#uploadimage");
    var fd = new FormData;
    var number = document.getElementById('number');
    var type = document.getElementById('type_doc');
    var date = document.getElementById('date');
    var desc = document.getElementById('description');
    var ammount = document.getElementById('sum');
    var procent = document.getElementById('nds');
    var nds = document.querySelector('input[name="nds_calc"]:checked').value;


    fd.append('file', $input.prop('files')[0]);
    fd.append('number', number.value);
    fd.append('type', type.value);
    fd.append('date', date.value);
    fd.append('desc', desc.value);
    fd.append('ammount', ammount.value);
    fd.append('procent', procent.value);
    fd.append('nds_calc', nds);

    $.ajax({
      url: '/upload_and_send',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
          global_doc_id = data.Doc_id;
          alert('Документ сохранен,выберите адрессата и нажмите кнопку отправить');
        } else {
          alert(data.message);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function send() {
    var fd = new FormData;
    var company_id_getter = document.getElementById("com_send").value;
    var company_id_sender = '{{$i->id}}';

    if (global_doc_id != "") {
      fd.append('company_id_getter', company_id_getter);
      fd.append('company_id_sender', company_id_sender);
      fd.append('doc_id', global_doc_id);
    } else {
      return (alert("Документ не загружен"));
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/ajax_send',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
          alert('Сообщение отправлено');
          $scope.doSign(global_doc_id);  // От сюда требуется вызвать функцию как правильно здесь написать
        } else {
          alert(data);
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Подозреваю, что `$scope` у вас не определена или в `$scope` нет функции `doSign`. Выведете эти значения в консоль и станет понятнее